# Is The Windows 8 Desktop An "App"?

Tags: windows-8

I'm not sure if this is just me. When I go to the desktop interface in Windows 8, I open it just like I would open an "app" like Music or the Internet. It almost feels tacked on, and upon first supposition, I thought it had been replaced entirely by the new home screen. So it seems to me like it is an app. From a technical perspective, could the Desktop be considered an app?

Comment: This very likely falls into the not-constructive category, as the definition of "app" is going be opinionated.  Explorer.exe is what creates the classic desktop, and so is just as much an app as the metro interface

Comment: Why was this closed? Not everyone knows what "explorer.exe" is, and what it does. I wasn't trying to ask whether an executable file can be called an application, I was asking if the desktop is an executable file, and what kind of conclusions can we draw from that?

Comment: "what kind of conclusions we can draw" is a discussion, which is best covered in a forum.  meta.superuser.com is the best place for a re-open request.

Comment: alrighr, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really since the Desktop was not coded with HTML5/CSS/JS/C#/etc technologies unlike the other apps. The desktop also does not follow the same Metro, Modern (what ever you want to call it) UI protocols like the other apps. (ie. No app screen. Desktop is not entirely Metro, Modern UI based)

Answer (score 0):

The desktop 'app' is still `explorer.exe`

Answer (score 0):

The windows 8 is designed to double up as a desktop OS + a tablet OS. And sometimes, for example, for devices, which can do both at the same time like the Surface.

Desktop is not just an app. Rather, you can consider it as a shortcut which opens up the old Windows interface.